# Quick Sort algorithm not working properly

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have created a code for quick sorting the only problem is that sometimes it gives out the sorted array and sometimes it doesn't. Any idea as to why it would do that? The first part of always works obviously.. the part where it shows the array TO BE sorted but the next part shows up occasionally after I run it a lot of time.

This is part of my code:

```
public static final int max = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] toSortArray = new int[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        toSortArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    System.out.println("The array to be sorted is:");

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        System.out.print(" | " + toSortArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" | ");

    // Beginning of the algorithm
    quicksortHelper(toSortArray, 0, max - 1);
    // End of the algorithm

    System.out.println("The sorted array is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        System.out.print(" | " + toSortArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" | ");
}

private static void quicksortHelper(int[] toSortArray, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
        int splitpoint = partition(toSortArray, first, last);
        quicksortHelper(toSortArray, first, splitpoint - 1);
        quicksortHelper(toSortArray, splitpoint + 1, last);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] toSortArray, int first, int last) {
    int pivot = toSortArray[first];
    int leftmark = first + 1;
    int rightmark = last;
    boolean done = true;

    while (done) {
        while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[leftmark] < pivot) {
            leftmark++;
        }

        while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[rightmark] > pivot) {
            rightmark--;
        }

        if (leftmark > rightmark) {
            done = false;
        } else {
            int temp = toSortArray[leftmark];
            toSortArray[leftmark] = toSortArray[rightmark];
            toSortArray[rightmark] = temp;
        }
    }

    int temp = toSortArray[rightmark];
    toSortArray[rightmark] = toSortArray[first];
    toSortArray[first] = temp;
    return rightmark;
}
```

Comment: We need more info. Do you get no output at all when it fails? Can you give us an example of input that makes it fail?

Comment: Why `leftmark` starts at `first + 1`?

Comment: Basically it always shows the array TO BE sorted and doesn't go to the algorithm part at all... it doesn't give errors but just doesn't show the the sorted array at all

Comment: Actually I think I figured out the problem.... It doesn't show the sorted array if there are duplicated in the array... and since I am pulling up random numbers theres a good chance for duplicates... Is that how quick sorts usually work?

Comment: Looks like when you have duplicated values, this condition: `if (leftmark > rightmark)` doesn't get fulfilled, thus always falling in an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I will try to work around it. I have another question. Is this the right implementation of quick sort?

Comment: Find the smallest failing input you can. Step through execution with that using a debugger. You will understand your code better. You will find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a program that I have written from your code and it works great

```
class QuickSort{
  public static final int max = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] toSortArray = new int[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      toSortArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    }

    System.out.println("The array to be sorted is:");

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      System.out.print(" | " + toSortArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" | ");

    // Beginning of the algorithm
    quicksortHelper(toSortArray, 0, max - 1);
    // End of the algorithm

    System.out.println("The sorted array is: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      System.out.print(" | " + toSortArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(" | ");
  }

  private static void quicksortHelper(int[] toSortArray, int first, int last) {
    if (first < last) {
      int splitpoint = partition(toSortArray, first, last);
      quicksortHelper(toSortArray, first, splitpoint - 1);
      quicksortHelper(toSortArray, splitpoint + 1, last);
    }
  }

  private static int partition(int[] array, int first, int last) {
    int temp;
    // Always assumes pivot index is first
    int pivot = array[first];

    // Swap Pivot and Last
    array[first] = array[last];
    array[last] = pivot;

    int mark = first;

    for(int i=first;i<last;i++){
      if(array[i] <= pivot){
        temp = array[mark];
        array[mark] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        mark++;
      }
    }

    temp = array[last];
    array[mark] = array[last];
    array[last] = temp;

    return mark;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing either

```
    while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[leftmark] < pivot) {
        leftmark++;
    }
```

to

```
    while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[leftmark] <= pivot) {
        leftmark++;
    }
```

or,

```
    while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[rightmark] > pivot) {
        rightmark--;
    }
```

to

```
    while (leftmark <= rightmark && toSortArray[rightmark] >= pivot) {
        rightmark--;
    }
```

(That is, change the `<` to `<=` *or* `>` to `>=`.)

This will ensure that it doesn't quit when it comes to a non-unique value.